# Wrong values in gtree

Tags: c, glib

I'm trying to use `gtree`, which comes from `glib`. 
I'm getting wrong values(always 0)  in s variable while iterating it like that:

```
gboolean iter_all(gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer data) {
  int *s =  (int *)value;
  printf("\n%s%d \n", (char *)key, *s);
  return FALSE;
} 

GTree* t = g_tree_new((GCompareFunc)g_ascii_strcasecmp);
readFilec(t);
g_tree_foreach(t, (GTraverseFunc)iter_all, NULL);
```

I set up the tree like this:

```
void readFilec(GTree *tree)
{
  FILE *fp = fopen("cfg/file.csv", "rb" );
  char * line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;

  if (fp == NULL)
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  char *p1;
  int  p2;
  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
  {
    printf("%s", line);
    p1 = strtok(line, "|");
    p2 = (int)atoi(strtok(NULL, "|"));
    g_tree_insert(tree,(gpointer ) g_strdup(p1), (gpointer )  &p2);

    printf("-%s%d ", p1, p2);

  }

  if (line)
  free(line);
  //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

The file which I read looks like that:

```
cfg/file.csv
AA1.E|1 
AA2.E|2
```

Comment: You are adding to the tree a pointer to a local variable (p2). What happpens when the program exits readFile() and p2 is destroyed?

Comment: That was the problem. I've assumed, that the tree mallocs on it own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment already identified the issue (you are inserting a pointer to a local stack variable into the tree), but there are still a few less serious issues. When storing `int` in a `GTree`, it's better to use it as the pointer value directly, e.g.:

```
gboolean iter_all(gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer data) {
    int s =  (int) value;
    printf("\n%s%d \n", (char *)key, s);
    return FALSE;
} 
...
g_tree_insert(tree, (gpointer) g_strdup(p1), (gpointer) p2);
```

To avoid memory leaks, you also need to specify a destroy function to free the string keys:

```
GTree* t = g_tree_new_full((GCompareFunc) g_ascii_strcasecmp,
                           NULL, g_free, NULL);
```

Comment: for storing integers in pointers, it's good practice to use GINT_TO_POINTER, to make it clear what's happening.